# How to save radio button's value into a mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to save the result of the radio button into a database. A user can only vote one time. When a returning user with the same email, tries to vote, the system alerts the user with an error message. I have included the html and php code below.

```
 foodID (int primary Auto increment)
    foodName (names of four food)
    foodRate(rating to be updated if a user clicked +1)
    email(email address)
    
        <form id="form_poll" action="includes/result.php" method="post">
            
            <div id="email">
           <label><span>Email : </span>  <input type="text" name="email" class="email" size="50px"  placeholder="Your Email here"  required></label><br />
            </div>
            <table>
            
            <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th></th>
                                <th></th>
                                <th></th>
                                <th></th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                            <td>
                            <label class="rad"> <input type="radio" class="btn" name="button" value="1" alt=""><i><img src="images/burger.png" alt="bulls burger" id="image1">
                            </i></label>
                            </td>
                            </tr>
                 
                                <tr>
                                <td ><label class="rad"> <input type="radio" class="btn" name="button" value="2" alt=""><i><img src="images/pizza.png" alt="pizza" id="image2"></i></label></td>
                                </tr>
                                
                                <tr>
                                <td ><label class="rad"> <input type="radio" class="btn" name="button" value="3" alt=""><i><img src="images/bol.png" alt="pasta b" id="image2"></i></label></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                <td ><label class="rad"> <input type="radio" class="btn" name="button" value="4" alt=""><i><img src="images/lasania.png" alt="pasta l" id="image2"></i></label></td>
                                </tr><br />
                                
                            </tbody>
                       
            </table> 
        in result.php
        <?php 
    $connect =include('connection.php');
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        if(isset($_POST['button'], $_POST['email']))
        {
            
        //mysqli_query($connect, "UPDATE poll SET 

        }
        else
        {
            echo"you did not select you choice";
        }
    }
    
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not add the email address as well and then check if they've already voted using the email address? 
you could use cookies or sessions but they're a little more complicated for you at the moment :) Keep it simple!!

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(isset($_POST['button'])&&isset($_POST['email'])){
        //not sure what you're using to add to database but I use mysqli object
        //$DBH being your database handler

        $query=$DBH->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM poll WHERE email=?');
        $query->bind_param('s',$_POST['email']);
        $query->execute();
        $query->bind_result($count);
        $query->close();
        if($count>0)echo"You've already used this email address to vote!";
        else{
            $update=$DBH->prepare('INSERT INTO poll (email,vote) VALUES(?,?)';
            $update->bind_param('si',$_POST['email'],$_POST['button']);
            $update->execute();
            $update->close();
            echo"you have successfully voted! Thank you!";
        }
    }elseif(!isset($_POST['email']))echo"No email address enter";
    elseif(!isset{$_POST['button']))echo"You've not selected a vote";
}
```

you can always add a session to your script but bare in mind sessions only last about 20 minutes or whatever your server is set to.

Just edit the second condition to

```
if(isset($_POST['button'])&&isset($_POST['email'])&&$_SESSION['alreadyVoted']!==true)
```

Also! Add to the group of else if statements towards the end of the script another else statement

```
elseif($_SESSION['alreadyVoted']===true)echo"You've already voted! :O using sessions";
```

Also! Under '`echo"you have successfully voted! thank you!";`' add this line:

```
$_SESSION['alreadyVoted']=true;
```

And ya done :d if you need any further help or for me to explain anything, let me know :)

Comment: Sorry! Had a syntax error on my second line! I've fixed the above but not sure what else you've done to your code.

Comment: Also! If you're using my exact code, you'll want to make sure your SQL is correct and that you've created the `$DBH` object like this: `$DBH=new mysqli('root','user','pass','database');`

Comment: your prepared statement must be wrong? Try creating the object and correcting the query. try this: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php

Comment: i changed the the my connection as you said to object like $DBH = ... but and now i get Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\web\polling\includes\result.php on line 9

Comment: I can't really tell what the error is unless I can see the code you're using and your sql database :d

Comment: ahh! sorry! I'm guessing it'll be the sql query then, make sure it's connected to a database and that the table names and columns are correct :)

Comment: Make sure your table name and columns are correct :) this should solve the problem!

Comment: i am so close please help

Comment: i do not want another foodID but instead i want the nubber to be added in the foodRating section

Comment: @hamza n_n that's ok! Thanks for accepting my answer :)